# Does std::bind keep a reference/copy of the object if I bind it to "this"?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I have a simple class F.

```
class F{
  public: 
    F(string const & name):name_(name){}
    void print(){ cout << name_ << endl;}
    std::function<void()> binder(){
      return std::bind(&F::print,this);
    }
};
```

Now if I instantiate a new class, call `binder`, delete the object, call the function returned by binder, I still get to see a the correct value. Something like this

```
F * f = new F("hello");
function<void()> func = f->binder();
delete f;
func(); // prints hello
```

Does the bind function keep a copy/reference to the object? At the risk of sounding stupid, does it belong to the stack or the heap?

P.S- I'm using clang++ on MacOSx, but I've tested this on g++ as well.

Comment: You pass a pointer, it keeps a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

std::bind takes parameters by value, so it keeps a copy of your this pointer (and not the object).  It is your responsibility to keep the object alive at least as long as func is valid.

Comment: You're assuming that "undefined behavior" means "crash". "Seems to work" is a very common (and unfortunate) effect of undefined behavior. Your clang++ should support asan and msan, which are special modes specifically designed to uncover memory orders like these; use them.

Comment: @AmanGupta Your program exhibits **undefined behavior**, so _anything_ can happen, including the function apparently working as normal. What's probably happening is that `bind` made a copy of `this` (which equals `f`, and incidentally `f` is not NULL'd out after `delete` either). When you call `func()`, you are essentially doing `f->print()` where `f` is a dangling pointer at this point. The reason it "works" is that even though `f` has been deallocated, its memory has been left intact, so it still works as if it were still allocated.